# Odoo v10 "Field timesheet_ids does not exist"

Tags: python, xml, odoo, field, project

project.issue model has timesheet_ids field which is one2Many to account.analytic.line. I am creating Wizard for project_issue.project_issue_form_view. form has timesheet page:

```
<page string="Timesheets" attrs="{'invisible': [('project_id', '=', False)]}" modifiers="{'invisible': [['project_id', '=', false]]}">
            <field name="timesheet_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1" context="{'default_user_id' : uid, 'default_project_id': project_id}" modifiers="{}"/>
        </page>
```

It is created via extension view. When I try to add field in to wizard, I get 'Field `timesheet_ids` does not exist. Can anybody point me what could be the issue here?

```
<record id="project_issue_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">project.task.wizard.name</field>
        <field name="model">project.issue</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Project Issue Wizard">
                <group>
                    <field name="timesheet_ids"/>
                </group>
                <footer>
                    <button name="create_request"
                        string="Finished" type="object"
                        class="btn-primary"/>
                    <button string="Cancel"
                        class="btn-default"
                        special="cancel" />
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, My view took priority and loaded first then the one which creates timesheet_ids field. I only needed to set priority field...

Comment: You catch it correctly. Most of the time developer ignore that attributes while they inherit any view.